# Don't serialize Caliburn.Micro IsNotifying property

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, caliburn.micro

I'm implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in my ModelBase class so that all of my derived classes have access to the INotifyPropertyChanged methods and events.

I'm using Caliburn.Micro in my project so I was doing this by implementing INotifyPropertyChangedEx in my IModelBase interface and then extending PropertyChangedBase in my ModelBase class.

This all works great, except that the IsNotifying property from PropertyChangedBase is getting serialized with my models. I tried a few things but haven't been able to get it to stop serializing.

I tried overriding IsNotifying in ModelBase and added [XmlIgnore] to the property. I also tried hiding IsNotifying by using the new keyword in my ModelBase class. Neither of these worked.

I copied the PropertyChangedBase code from github, put it into my own PropertyChangedBase class, and then added [XmlIgnore] to the IsNotifying property. This worked, but isn't ideal.

Any ideas? Can this be done? Should I just scrap using the Caliburn.Micro PropertyChangedBase and implement my own? It isn't difficult to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I was just trying to use the one in Caliburn.Micro since I'm already using the library.

This is a simple example that writes the XML to the console

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace CaliburnPropertyChangedBase
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var myModel = new MyModel {SomeProperty = "Test"};

            Console.WriteLine(myModel.SerializeObject());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class XmlHelper
    {
        public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize)
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());

            using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IModelBase : INotifyPropertyChangedEx
    {
    }

    public class ModelBase : PropertyChangedBase, IModelBase
    {
    }

    public interface IMyModel : IModelBase
    {
        string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyModel : ModelBase, IMyModel
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <IsNotifying>true</IsNotifying>
  <SomeProperty>Test</SomeProperty>
</MyModel>
```

Comment: As a note, the fact that it's serializing that property isn't a train smash. It doesn't cause any issues with my application. It's just not right to have it there. If someone else were to consume our XML, we would have to tell them to ignore that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SerializeObject<T>` method, try this:

```
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof(PropertyChangedBase), "IsNotifying", new XmlAttributes
{
    XmlIgnore = true,
});
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType(), overrides);
```

The `XmlAttributeOverrides` type lets you customize everything that can be done using xml serializer attributes - *but at runtime*. I was amazed when I found out.

Further reading: [.NET Framework Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides?view=netframework-4.7)

Comment: This is perfect. I just gave it a test and it works as required.